# show that there exists one and only one matrix $X$ such that $A=BX$ and one and only one matrix $Y$ such that $A=YB$ if $B$ is non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning

> If $A$ is a given matrix and $B$ is a non-singular matrix(both of order $n$),then show that there exists one and only one matrix $X$ such that $A=BX$ and one and only one matrix $Y$ such that $A=YB$.

I don't know how to prove the above. I know that rank if a matrix remains same after pre-multiplication or post multiplication by a non-singular matrix. Does this fact help at all in proving the above? Or is there some other way?

Please anyone help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B$ is non-singular, it means that $B$ is invertible: there exists $B^{-1}$ with $B^{-1}B=BB^{-1}=I$. If you multiply $A=BX$ by $B^{-1}$ on the left, you get $B^{-1}A=X$. That's the only possible value of $X$. Similar with the other equation.

Comment: Ohh...got it. Thank you.